# Error when generating Visual Studio project files (.sln for Unreal)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

For understanding, here is a project from github: [link](https://github.com/tomlooman/SimpleFPSTemplate) `GitHub link Project`

I have Unreal Engine 4 4.17 and 4.18 installed and Visual Studio 2017 IDE versions. When I'm press a button to generate VS .sln files, it gives this error:

```
"Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.17/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/NAME/Downloads/SimpleFPSTemplate-ue4.17/FPSGame.uproject" -game -rocket -progress -log="C:\Users\NAME\Downloads\SimpleFPSTemplate-ue4.17/Saved/Logs/UnrealVersionSelector-2021.08.17-18.42.01.log"

UnrealBuildTool Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: ?? 㤠???? ????? ????? ???? "c:\users\NAME\downloads\simplefpstemplate-ue4.17\saved\logs\unrealversionselector-2021.08.17-18.42.01.log".

   ? System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

   ? System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

   ? System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)

   ? UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.GuardedMain(String[] Arguments)

   ? UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.Main(String[] Arguments)"
```

If I just try to run the project, I get a error about missing FPSGame.dll

I tried to change the UE4 version from 4.17 to 4.18, and back. I have reinstalled both versions of the UE4 game engine. I have reinstalled IDE VS 2017 version. I checked the engine files for both versions. But it still gives an error. I ran VS, EGLauncher, UE4 as administrator. I moved the project from downloads to a folder created by the UE4 engine - Unreal Projects. I removed the space bar in Unreal Projects. I moved it to desktop, and Program files - no difference, i still get errors.

It's a text from log in saved/logs folder:

```
Log file open, 08/17/21 18:52:03

LogWindows: Failed to load 'aqProf.dll' (GetLastError=126)

LogWindows: File 'aqProf.dll' does not exist

LogWindows: Failed to load 'VSPerf140.dll' (GetLastError=126)

LogWindows: File 'VSPerf140.dll' does not exist

LogWindows: Failed to load 'VtuneApi.dll' (GetLastError=126)

LogWindows: File 'VtuneApi.dll' does not exist

LogWindows: Failed to load 'VtuneApi32e.dll' (GetLastError=126)

LogWindows: File 'VtuneApi32e.dll' does not exist

LogInit: Display: Running engine for game: FPSGame

LogPlatformFile: Not using cached read wrapper

LogInit: Display: RandInit(-1859720771) SRandInit(-1859720770).

LogTaskGraph: Started task graph with 5 named threads and 20 total threads with 3 sets of task threads.

LogStats: Stats thread started at 0.353053

LogD3D11RHI: Aftermath initialized

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Paper2D

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LightPropagationVolume

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CodeLiteSourceCodeAccess

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GitSourceControl

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin KDevelopSourceCodeAccess

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin NullSourceCodeAccess

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PerforceSourceControl

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SubversionSourceControl

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin UObjectPlugin

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin VisualStudioSourceCodeAccess

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin XCodeSourceCodeAccess

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AssetManagerEditor

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AudioCapture

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin FacialAnimation

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GameplayTagsEditor

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MobileLauncherProfileWizard

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PluginBrowser

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SpeedTreeImporter

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AlembicImporter

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CharacterAI

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin HTML5Networking

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidMedia

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AvfMedia

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MediaPlayerEditor

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WmfMedia

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin TcpMessaging

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin UdpMessaging

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LevelSequenceEditor

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MatineeToLevelSequence

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemGooglePlay

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemIOS

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystem

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemNull

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemUtils

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidDeviceProfileSelector

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidMoviePlayer

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidPermission

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AppleMoviePlayer

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ArchVisCharacter

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CableComponent

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CustomMeshComponent

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ExampleDeviceProfileSelector

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GoogleCloudMessaging

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ImmediatePhysics

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin IOSDeviceProfileSelector

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LinuxDeviceProfileSelector

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LocationServicesBPLibrary

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MobilePatchingUtils

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OculusVR

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PhysXVehicles

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ProceduralMeshComponent

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin RuntimePhysXCooking

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SteamVR

LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WindowsMoviePlayer

LogInit: Warning: Incompatible or missing module: UE4Editor-FPSGame.dll

LogExit: Preparing to exit.

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module AnimationModifiers (36)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PropertyEditor (35)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module AudioEditor (32)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module TextureCompressor (30)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module ShaderCore (28)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module Landscape (26)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module SlateRHIRenderer (24)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module OpenGLDrv (22)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module D3D11RHI (20)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module AnimGraphRuntime (18)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module Renderer (16)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module Engine (14)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module CoreUObject (12)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module NetworkFile (10)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module CookedIterativeFile (8)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module StreamingFile (6)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module SandboxFile (4)

LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PakFile (2)

LogExit: Exiting.

Log file closed, 08/17/21 18:52:05
```

Comment: Logs mention `UE4Editor-FPSGame.dll` file, does it exist?

Comment: @Top-Master This project has 2 versions, with dll file, and without. But what with the dll file, what without, complains about dll file at startup anyway. Despite the fact that other users, everything is fine. Although the same problem as mine, many people have. But there is always something a little different and everyone has their own solutions, someone just had enough to launch UE4 with the admin' properties, someone had to remove the space in the project folder.
As for the size, as I said, I reinstalled both versions of the engines several times, they work fine, except for this project.

Comment: UPD: For some reason, the project generates files correctly if you select the latest version of UE4 4.26
Although the project was made on version 4.17 and for other people, it also runs even on 4.18 - correctly. I have reinstalled 3 times 4.17 and 4.18 already. It is still unclear.
But my problem is, that I need this only on 4.17 or 4.18, not newer.

Comment: For understanding, here is a project from github: [link](https://github.com/tomlooman/SimpleFPSTemplate) `Project`

Comment: What is the advantage of UE 4.17 version? (Does it support older Android versions?) Anyway, the repo you linked has special branch for UE 4.17, so clone that like `git clone ... -b UE-4.17`

Comment: I already did it, but nothing changet.